# Создается 2 иконки приложения

Tags: java, android

Причина проблемы скорее всего в нем, так как при его редактировании вторая иконка пропадает. Проблема появилась после решения сделать экран загрузки по этой [статье](https://ustimov.org/posts/29/).

Comment: Решил проблему заменив на <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />

Comment: Иконка создаётся для каждой активити, у которой в манифесте есть вот это: `<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>`

Comment: Спасибо ЮрийСпб